# Telethon, how to get an entity?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I started using [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) to integrate a python app with telegram API. I was able to get it started and send a few messages.

The function for sending messages gets an entity as the first argument. So far I was getting this entity from the get_dialogs function which returns list of entities. I know which group I want to send messages to and don't want to go through get_dialogs every time to get the entity.

**So which function can I use to give me an entity to pass it to send message?** 
I am expecting there should be a function which gets a group id (or a similar unique feature from the group) as an input and passes me the entity in response. But so far I wasn't able to locate any function.

```
def send_message(self,
                     entity,# <--------------- how can I get this entity?
                     message,
                     markdown=False,
                     no_web_page=False):
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could potentially save the group/chat/user or anything you want in a external file, if you don't want to query it each time. What [`send_message`](https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/methods/messages/send_message.html)  actually takes is an [`InputPeer`](https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/types/input_peer.html), that can be, in your case, an [`InputChat`](https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/constructors/input_peer_chat.html).

Assuming you know what the ID of your chat is, you can do the following:

```
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerChat

chat = InputPeerChat(desired_chat_id)
client.send_message(chat, 'your message')
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: I was able to send message to groups with InputPeerChat, but not supergroups and channels. Is there another method I should use to convert supergroup id or channel id to entity? For channels I get this error: telethon.errors.RPCError: (RPCError(...), 'Invalid object ID for a chat. Make sure to pass the right types.')

Comment: actually I figured out the channels, using InputPeerChannel and passing access_hash as the 2nd parameter. But for supergroups still not sure which method to use.

Comment: @apadana supergroups should be considered channels, so try that?

Comment: supergroups should be considered channels: yes, worked great!